# lista enlazada me guía a un valor basura

Tags: c++, lista, nodos

El problema en si es bastante explicativo. cuando hago una lista enlazada como puntero, al imprimirla me dirige a un valor basura.

El código es el siguiente

**main:**

```
   Lista<int>* lis1;
  Lista <int>*lis2;

    int n,m;
  cout<<"ingrese el tamaño de la primera lista"<<endl;
  cin>>n;

  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    lis1->insertar(i,i+1);


  }


  lis1->print();

    cout<<endl;
  cout<<"ingrese el tamaño de la segunda lista"<<endl;
  cin>>m;

  for (int j=0;j<m;j++){
    lis2->insertar(j,j+1);

  }
  lis2->print();
cout<<endl;
```

**lista.h:**

```
#ifndef U02_LISTAS_LISTA_LISTA_H_
#define U02_LISTAS_LISTA_LISTA_H_
#include "nodo.h"


template <class T> class Lista {
private:
  Nodo<T> *inicio;

public:
  Lista();

  Lista(const Lista<T> &li);

  ~Lista();

  bool esVacia();

  int getTamanio();

  void insertar(int pos, T dato);

  void insertarPrimero(T dato);

  void insertarUltimo(T dato);

  void remover(int pos);

  T getDato(int pos);

  void reemplazar(int pos, T dato);

  void vaciar();

  void print();

  void sumar(int dato);
};


template <class T> Lista<T>::Lista() { inicio = nullptr; }


template <class T> Lista<T>::Lista(const Lista<T> &li) { inicio = li.inicio; }


template <class T> Lista<T>::~Lista() { vaciar(); }

template <class T> bool Lista<T>::esVacia() { return inicio == nullptr; }


template <class T> int Lista<T>::getTamanio() {
  Nodo<T> *aux = inicio;
  int size = 0;

  while (aux != nullptr) {
    aux = aux->getSiguiente();
    size++;
  }

  return size;
}



template <class T> void Lista<T>::insertar(int pos, T dato) {
  int posActual = 0;
  Nodo<T> *aux = inicio, *nuevo;
  nuevo = new Nodo<T>;
  nuevo->setDato(dato);

  if (pos == 0) {
    nuevo->setSiguiente(inicio);
    inicio = nuevo;
    return;
  }

  while (aux != nullptr && posActual < pos - 1) {
    aux = aux->getSiguiente();
    posActual++;
  }

  if (aux == nullptr) {
    throw 404;
  }

  nuevo->setSiguiente(aux->getSiguiente());
  aux->setSiguiente(nuevo);
}


template <class T> void Lista<T>::insertarPrimero(T dato) { insertar(0, dato); }


template <class T> void Lista<T>::insertarUltimo(T dato) {
  Nodo<T> *aux = inicio, *nuevo;
  nuevo = new Nodo<T>;
  nuevo->setDato(dato);

  if (aux == nullptr) {
    nuevo->setSiguiente(inicio);
    inicio = nuevo;
    return;
  }

  while (aux->getSiguiente() != nullptr) {
    aux = aux->getSiguiente();
  }

  nuevo->setSiguiente(aux->getSiguiente());
  aux->setSiguiente(nuevo);
}

template <class T> void Lista<T>::remover(int pos) {
  Nodo<T> *aux = inicio, *aBorrar;
  int posActual = 0;

  if (pos == 0) {
    inicio = inicio->getSiguiente();
    delete aux;
    return;
  }

  while (aux != nullptr && posActual < pos - 1) {
    aux = aux->getSiguiente();
    posActual++;
  }

  if (aux == nullptr) {
    throw 404;
  }

  aBorrar = aux->getSiguiente();
  aux->setSiguiente(aBorrar->getSiguiente());

  delete aBorrar;
}


template <class T> T Lista<T>::getDato(int pos) {
  Nodo<T> *aux = inicio;
  int posActual = 0;

  while (aux != nullptr && posActual < pos) {
    aux = aux->getSiguiente();
    posActual++;
  }

  if (aux == nullptr) {
    throw 404;
  }

  return aux->getDato();
}

template <class T> void Lista<T>::reemplazar(int pos, T dato) {
  Nodo<T> *aux = inicio;
  int posActual = 0;

  while (aux != nullptr && posActual < pos) {
    aux = aux->getSiguiente();
    posActual++;
  }

  if (aux == nullptr) {
    throw 404;
  }

  aux->setDato( dato );
}


template <class T> void Lista<T>::vaciar() {
    Nodo<T> *aux = inicio, *aBorrar;

    while( aux != nullptr ){
        aBorrar = aux;
        aux = aux->getSiguiente();
        delete aBorrar;
    }

    inicio = nullptr;

}

template<class T>
void Lista<T>::print() {
    Nodo<T> *aux = inicio;

    while (aux != nullptr) {
        std::cout << aux->getDato() << "->";
        aux = aux->getSiguiente();
    }
    std::cout << "NULL" << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
  void Lista<T>::sumar(int dato){
Nodo <T> *aux= inicio;

int sum=0;

while (aux!=nullptr){
    if(aux->getDato()>dato){
        sum += aux->getDato();

    }

   aux = aux->getSiguiente();
}
std::cout<<sum;


}


#endif // U02_LISTAS_LISTA_LISTA_H_
```

**Nodo.h:**

```
#ifndef NODO_H
#define NODO_H

template<class T>
class Nodo{
    private:
        T dato;
        Nodo<T> *siguiente;
    
    public:
       T getDato(){
           return dato;
       }

       void setDato(T d){
           dato = d;
       }

       Nodo<T> *getSiguiente(){
           return siguiente;
       }

       void setSiguiente(Nodo<T> *siguiente){
           this->siguiente = siguiente;
       }


};

#endif //NODO_H
```

En cuanto ejecuto el programa e imprimo la lista, me sale esto:

> ingrese el tama±o de la primera lista

> 5

> 1->2->3->4->5->1432107587->

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

¿Cuál seria el problema? porque si no declaro Lis1 y lis2 como punteros, el programa funciona bien. He intentado cambiar Lista.h y no afectó el desempeño en nada.

Comment: Creas un puntero a un `Lista<int>` pero nunca le asignas una
direccion de memoria valida, asi que al dereferenciarlo
para realizar operaciones, caes en comportamiento indefinido.
En ese caso es tan valido que funcione, que falle, o cualquier otra cosa.
*"porque si no declaro Lis1 y lis2 como punteros, el programa
funciona bien"* Eso es porque si no los declaras como
punteros van a tener un espacio de memoria asignado en el
stack. Si los vas a usar como punteros tienes que asignarles
tu una direccion de memoria valida.

Answer (score 0):

El error `0xC0000005` se corresponde a un [acceso no válido a la memoria](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=0xC0000005+%5BC%2B%2B%5D), el cuál se da porque no has dado valor al puntero `lis1` y sin embargo lo estás usando:

```
    Lista<int>* lis1; // sin valor
    Lista <int>*lis2; // sin valor

    int n,m;
    cout<<"ingrese el tamaño de la primera lista"<<endl;
    cin>>n;

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        lis1->insertar(i,i+1); // 'lis1' no tiene valor, comportamiento indefinido
```

Eso es un "[*comportamiento indefinido*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido)" (CI). Cuando el compilador se encuentra con un CI puede tomar decisiones bizarras<sup>1</sup> como hacer que tu código no funcione, funcione de manera extraña (como es tu caso) o algunas personas creen que puede [invocar demonios en tus fosas nasales](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon).

Para evitar esta situación puedes:

1. Rellenar los punteros:

   ```
   Lista<int> *lis1 = new Lista<int>();
   Lista>int> *lis2 = new Lista<int>();
   ```
2. No usar punteros:

   ```
   Lista<int> lis1;
   Lista>int> lis2;
   ```

Te aconsejo la segunda opción.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Bizarro, ra](https://dle.rae.es/bizarro):  Del it. *bizzarro* 'iracundo'. adj. valiente (‖ arriesgado).